# Add a line of text to Excel sheet in openxlsx in R

Tags: r, export

Consider the following code:

`install.packages("openxlsx")
library(openxlsx)
d <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
write.xlsx(d, "test.xlsx")`

However, I want to add a line of text in the top of Excel sheet. I know I can use `cat(paste0(), file = )` with write.table, but I am not sure with openxlsx.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write "text" to your workbook the same way you can write data to your workbook.

```
library(openxlsx)

d <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")

writeData(wb, "Sheet1", "This is an example", startCol = 1, startRow = 1)
writeData(wb, "Sheet1", d, startCol = 1, startRow = 3, rowNames = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

The code above produces the following Excel file:

[image]

Comment: If the line you want to add needs to cover multiple cells, the syntax that works in that case is:
`writeData(wb, "Sheet1", list("Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3, "Cell4))`